# What am I doing wrong with this Scrollview?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I am attempting to set up a scroll view and every video I watch they say the same things:
•Make scrollview in VC
•Make it bound to all margins (0,0,0,0)
•Embed a content view inside of Scrollview
•Content view margins are (0,0,0,0)
•Set Equal heights & width from content view to superview
•set priority of height to 250

I have done this time and time again and cannot figure out why it still isn't working. Can someone please double check these screenshots?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Change the height constraint of the most inner view (in the first image) from `Proportional Height to View` to  `Equal Height`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some subviews into your content view and make sure to have a complete set of vertical constraints from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you go in the Size inspector under the "Scroll View" Section you can find the "Content Layout Guides" tick, disable and the errors will disappear[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you Set All the constraints to ScrollView and want to set its contents in code .. it remains complaining about its constraints because they remain ambiguous .. so to remove error from story board

what you do is set Ambiguity to never verify and error will go away .... hope it will help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have anything bound to your *Content Layout Guide*.

So basically you have two guides in Scroll View: *Frame* and *Content*.

*Frame Layout Guide* provides you the ability to bind to your `UIScrollView`'s frame. E.g. equal width between your Content view and Scroll View itself.

The most useful here is *Content Layout Guide*. Basically it helps to determine the scrollable content size of your `UIScrollView`'s contents.

So in your case you have to have a Content view inside your Scroll View that has equal width with *Frame Layout Guide* and have its edges pinned to *Content Layout Guide*. Like so:
[image: Proper constraints for the content view]

Oh, and do not forget to have your Content view have a determined height so your scroll view will calculate the size of its scrollable contents.